# Undefined name Patrol in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, widget-test-flutter, flutter-patrol

Even though I added dependency correctly, it is unable to find the Patrol class inside the dependencies. The correct implementation is shown in this link: https://pub.dev/packages/patrol

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Patrol` class has been renamed to `NativeAutomator`.